# Symfony: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server

Tags: postgresql, docker, symfony, migration

I have Symfon project on windows.
In docker it's running postgres database on port 57058:5432.
When I run `symfony console make:migration` I get this:

```
In ExceptionConverter.php line 77:

  An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)  
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting                                                                      
        TCP/IP connections on port 30000?                                                                                            


In Exception.php line 28:
                                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)  
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting                                 
        TCP/IP connections on port 30000?                                                       


In Driver.php line 35:

  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)  
        Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting                                 
        TCP/IP connections on port 30000?                                                       


make:migrationa
```

When I run `symfony var:export`

```
DATABASE_PORT=30000 DATABASE_USERNAME=main DATABASE_PASSWORD=main PGPORT=30000 PGPASSWORD=main SYMFONY_TUNNEL_ENV=1 SYMFONY_DOCKER_ENV=1 DATABASE_VERSION=15 DATABASE_NAME=main DATABASE_URL=postgres://main:main@127.0.0.1:30000/main?s
slmode=disable&charset=utf8&serverVersion=15 DATABASE_DATABASE=main DATABASE_DRIVER=postgres PGUSER=main DATABASE_SERVER=postgres://127.0.0.1:30000 SYMFONY_TUNNEL=main DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1 PGDATABASE=main DATABASE_USER=main PGHOS
T=127.0.0.1
```

Why there is port 30000?
In pgadmin I can connect with db on port 5432

My files:
.env

```
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=50232f36c947f58b7a7ca24b159c795e

DATABASE_URL="postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw

volumes:
  database_data:
```

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    ports:
      - "5432"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not have DATABASE=30000 somewhere ? Maybe in your .env or .env.local file ?

Comment: @DylanKAS Yes I am sure. I searched all the files for the occurrence of the phrase "30000" and found nothing

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct to suppose you are using Symfony?

Anyway here's my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-!ChangeMe!}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-app}
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database_data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

My `docker-compose.override.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    ports:
      - "5432"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
  mailer:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports: ["1025", "1080"]
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

And my `.env.local` file:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"
```

**Solution**

Setting a `HOST_PORT` in my `docker-compose.override.yml` file solved the problem:

```
 ###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
   database:
     ports:
-      - "5432"
+      - "5432:5432"
 ###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
 
 ###> symfony/mailer ###
   mailer:
     image: schickling/mailcatcher
-    ports: ["1025", "1080"]
+    ports: ["1025:1025", "1080:1080"]
 ###< symfony/mailer ###
```

**Explanations**

There are two syntaxes to specify the port number: `HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT` or just `CONTAINER_PORT`

The `HOST_PORT` is the port that will be accessible from outside of the container, ie by the host machine.
The `CONTAINER_PORT` is the port that will be open inside the container.

Docker will create a tunnel between these two ports and forward all incoming and outgoing requests and responses.

Note that if only one port (the `CONTAINER_PORT`) is specified, which is the case with Symfony's `docker-compose.override.yml`, Docker will choose the `HOST_PORT` at random. To find out which port is used you need to list the running the containers:

```
$ docker compose ps
NAME                     IMAGE                    COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
symfony-p11-database-1   postgres:15-alpine       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   database            2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32768->5432/tcp, :::32768->5432/tcp
symfony-p11-mailer-1     schickling/mailcatcher   "sh -c 'mailcatcher …"   mailer              2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:32770->1025/tcp, :::32770->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->1080/tcp, :::32769->1080/tcp
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                                      NAMES
e7852b394913   postgres:15-alpine       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:32768->5432/tcp, :::32768->5432/tcp                                                symfony-p11-database-1
c339ca9944b4   schickling/mailcatcher   "sh -c 'mailcatcher …"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:32770->1025/tcp, :::32770->1025/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->1080/tcp, :::32769->1080/tcp   symfony-p11-mailer-1
```

Here you can see that the `HOST_PORT` for the `postgres` container is `32768` and the `CONTAINER_PORT` is `5432`.

Thus you can adapt your `.env.local` as such:

```
- DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:5432/app?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"
+ DATABASE_URL="postgresql://app:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:32768/app?serverVersion=15&charset=utf8"
```

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for more information on port numbers.